# SQL Server : Dont know if my function is correct

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server Management Studio.

I have created a function called `func_GetMenuItemsForMenu` this function you will pass the ID of the Menu to the function. The function will find all MenuItems that are on the Menu. It will return a table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[func_GetMenuItemsForMenu] 

(

  @MenuItemMenuItemID NVARCHAR(200)

)

RETURNS TABLE

AS

   RETURN (

   SELECT Menu.MenuID FROM Menu, MenuItem

   WHERE MenuItem.MenuID LIKE @MenuItemMenuItemID + '%'

   AND MenuItem.MenuID = Menu.MenuID)

GO
```

I am trying to create a function that is named `func_GetMenuItemDescriptionForMenuItemID` 
 It should operate as expected in the title and pass `MenuItemID` to the function and return the `MenuItemDescription`, a scalar (varchar).

Here is what I have so far. I do not know if the following function is correct and will perform as stated above?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[func_GetMenuItemDescriptionForMenuItemID]
(  
 @MenuItemID nvarchar (200)   
)

RETURNS nvarchar (200)

AS

BEGIN    
  RETURN (SELECT TOP 5 MenuItemDescriptionText
          FROM MenuItem 
          WHERE MenuItemID = @MenuItemID)    
END
```

All tables/fields/relationships are shown in the database diagram below, all of the fields with ID in the title are int, the rest are varchar.

As shown the Fields MenuID in each table are a foreign key to the Table Menu field MenuID. As well the Field MenuGrouID in Table MenuItem is the foreign key for MenuGroupID in Table MenuGroup

[image: Database Diagram]

I need to use these 2 functions to create a single SQL Query or Stored Procedure that uses the function call to return the description of all menu items that appear on a given menu,  and am having trouble with as writing this query to begin with as well as seeing if my second function meets the criteria

Thank you for your input.

Comment: why you need to use Top5?  do multiple descriptions exist for single menuitem id?

Comment: No they do not, there should be 1 item per MenuItemID number, however there will be multiple entries 5 or so should be displayed

Comment: ok. try the function i gave in the answer also i mentioned how to call the function in the answer. i hope that helps !

Comment: Multiple entries in the menu? Then you want to find them by MenuID, not MenuItemID, looking by MenuItemID will only ever give you one result back, and your `top 5` is causing an issue code wise, as you have a scalar function.

Comment: @Jay Why would you ask us it's correct or not???  Can't you just run it???  We don't have the data, we don't know what you want.  Aren't you the one who has the data, and what you want??  Run it.  If it doesn't work, tell us what is wrong with the result.

Comment: I was trying to narrow down my problem specifically, but i guess I'm not getting something, I will edit the question with the full scope of my problem. I am very new to SQL thats why I am asking questions. I understand they may not come out the best.

Comment: If you want to get the top 5 of items in a menu, your parameter should be `MenuID` instead of `MenuItemID`.  You want to get top 5 of `MenuItemID` for a particular `MenuID`.

Answer (score 0):

You should return a scalar. `SELECT TOP 5...` returns [result set](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Result_set). You must declare a variable and assign the value you are looking for to it. Then return that variable.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[func_GetMenuItemDescriptionForMenuItemID]
(  
 @MenuItemID nvarchar (200)   
)

RETURNS nvarchar (200)

BEGIN
     DECLARE @ReturnVariable NVARCHAR(200);
     SELECT @ReturnVariable = MenuItemDescriptionText FROM MenuItem WHERE MenuItemID = @MenuItemID;
     RETURN @ReturnVariable;
END
```

Comment: @MenuItemID should be the name of the variable  I need that is why it was there

Comment: There. Sorry about that. I did not copy the first part of your code

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[func_GetMenuItemDescriptionForMenuItemID]
(  
 @MenuItemID nvarchar (200)   
)
RETURNS nvarchar (200)
AS
BEGIN    
  RETURN (SELECT MenuItemDescriptionText
          FROM MenuItem 
          WHERE MenuItemID = @MenuItemID)    
END
```

How to call function

replace '1007' with your item id

```
select [dbo].[func_GetMenuItemDescriptionForMenuItemID]('1007')
```

Comment: Ok ty, how can you modify to return either however many items there are, or an amount like the first 5 or so

Comment: the function i gave is scalar function. if you want to return set or top 5 you need to define Table-valued function. that is different use case.

Comment: @Jay. if you are happy with my answer please accept answer and feel free to vote

Answer (score 0):

You defined a Scalar valued function (a function that only returns a single value), what you want is a Table valued function (a function that returns multiple rows):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[func_GetMenuItemDescriptionForMenuItemID]
(  
 @MenuItemID nvarchar (200)   
)

RETURNS @results TABLE(description nvarchar (200))

AS

BEGIN  
INSERT INTO @results(description)
  SELECT TOP 5 MenuItemDescriptionText
          FROM MenuItem 
          WHERE MenuItemID = @MenuItemID
  RETURN 
END
```

However, as you are using `MenuItemID`, you will only ever get one result, since that is your primary key. I think what you wanted was to select based on `MenuID` which is the FK in that table. If you really want by MenuItemID you can just `SELECT MenuItemDescriptionText FROM MenuItem WHERE MenuItemID = @MenuItemID` which is honestly so simple a query it's not worth a function.